# ValueError: Cannot assign "<Truckdb: Truckdb object (1)>": "Quiz.truck_name" must be a "truck_name" instance

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to create an instance in my app like this:

Views.py

```
new_quiz = Quiz.objects.create(owner=request.user, comments="Autogenerated", truck_type=truck_type_object,
                                       truck_name=chosen_truck_object)
```

where `chosen_truck_object` is this:

```
    chosen_truck_object = Truckdb.objects.filter(display_name=chosentruck)[0]
```

And Models.py

```
class Quiz(models.Model):


    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes')
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    truck_type = models.ForeignKey(truck_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='trucks')
    truck_name = models.ForeignKey(truck_name, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class truck_type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='#007bff')

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name



class truck_name(models.Model):
    truck_type = models.ForeignKey(truck_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

How can I pass the `truck_type` and `truck_name` instance to the `Quiz` model in `Quiz.objects.create` ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to follow the naming convention guidelines, so your models' name must be camelcase [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) as like:

```
class TruckType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='#007bff')

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name



class TruckName(models.Model):
    truck_type = models.ForeignKey(TruckType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

And then please migrate your database and then for your problem you need to take `TruckName` object instead of `Truckdb`.

Comment: but there are no any field name `display_name` into `TruckName` model :(

Answer (score 0):

```
chosen_truck_object = TruckName.objects.filter(display_name=chosentruck)[0]
```

instead of filter use get method `chosen_truck_object = TruckName.objects.get(display_name=chosentruck)` it will save

Comment: but there is no any field name display_name into TruckName model :(